# incorporating ra-cognito in react-admin with ra-data-json-server promise problem

Tags: promise, aws-amplify, react-admin

I've been using my own implementation of authentication in react-admin (with cognito), but I want to switch to ra-cognito. However I can't figure out how to implement the Auth.currentSession() promise of AWS Amplify inside the httpClient of the ra-data-json-server.

My old/current code which is working fine:

```
import jsonServerProvider from 'ra-data-json-server';
const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({Accept: 'application/json'});
    }

    // cognitoIdToken item set on authentication 
    const cognitoIdToken = localStorage.getItem('cognitoIdToken');
    options.headers.set('Authorization', cognitoIdToken);

    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
}
```

My new code :

```
import jsonServerProvider from 'ra-data-json-server';
const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({Accept: 'application/json'});
    }

    return Auth.currentSession()
        .then(data => {
            options.headers.set('Authorization', data);
            console.log('Authorization set...', data);
        })
       .then(fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options));
}
```

The new code is obviously wrong, but I can't figure out to incorporate the Auth.currentSession promise into the httpClient function.

Answer (score 0):

Forgotten to return the result of the first promise oops...

```
import jsonServerProvider from 'ra-data-json-server';
const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({Accept: 'application/json'});
    }

    return Auth.currentSession()
        .then(data => {
            options.headers.set('Authorization', data);
            return options;
        })
        .then(options => 
            return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options)
        );
}
```