# ra-data-json-server in conjunction with ra-auth-cognito

Tags: reactjs, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, react-admin

Before I start, I'm very new to React but not so to AWS which has resulted in me picking off a project above my ability set it appears.

I'm building a very simple CRUD website which has a list of posts and a list of users who made those posts. I started off following this tutorial here https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html once at the end I started extending it out into an AWS deployment.

Ostensibly an S3 bucket with the React site, and API to provide the data interfaces all behind a cloudfront distribution.

I don't want every man and his dog to have access so I want to implement a Cognito authentication provider infront of my service, like this:

[image]

My issue is that the tutorial walks me through setting up a dataProvider using the `ra-data-json-server` module. The `ra-auth-cognito` module provides what I need for logging in and works correctly, valid Cognito users can log-in to the dashboard, though they cannot access any data via the API calls.

My App.tsx file contains

```
...
import { CognitoAuthProvider, Login } from 'ra-auth-cognito';
import { CognitoUserPool } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';

const userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
  UserPoolId: "us-east-1_MyPoOlId",
  ClientId: "MyClIeNtId",
});

const authProvider = CognitoAuthProvider(userPool);

export const App = () => (
  <Admin authProvider={authProvider} dataProvider={dataProvider} dashboard={Dashboard} loginPage={Login} >
    <Resource name="posts" list.......
```

My dataProvider.ts looks like

```
import jsonServerProvider from "ra-data-json-server";

// I know i need a httpClient function here (I think)

export const dataProvider = (() => {
    return jsonServerProvider("https://my-url/api/");
})();
```

I've been working through the documentation https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authentication.html which I understand lets me pass an httpClient in to the jsonServerProvider as a second parameter, the provided code block results in the error "The dataProvider threw an error. It should return a rejected Promise instead"

I've also tried following what this post advised [incorporating ra-cognito in react-admin with ra-data-json-server promise problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58058727/incorporating-ra-cognito-in-react-admin-with-ra-data-json-server-promise-problem) though this user is using Amplify which I am not however it doesn't work for me regardless

The issue is, I can now protect the admin panel, but doing anything which calls the backend API with authentication enabled isn't being sent the authentication, the API is expecting a Bearer Token which correctly replies with the data expected when I hit it through postman with a valid Bearer token.

How do I link the calls to the API in such a was that the logged in token is passed thro to the api calls made by the ra-data-json-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos for providing a detailed question to begin with :)

I believe you are missing two things to get it to work.

#### 1. Obtain the token for the currently logged user

`ra-auth-cognito` almost does it internally, but unfortunately it does not document how to obtain the JWT token for the currently logged user. Here's one way to get it (inspired by [`authProvider.ts`](https://github.com/marmelab/ra-auth-cognito/blob/main/packages/ra-auth-cognito/src/authProvider.ts#L224)):

```
        const getJwtToken = async () => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const user = userPool.getCurrentUser();

                if (!user) {
                    return reject();
                }

                user.getSession((err, session: CognitoUserSession) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return reject(err);
                    }
                    if (!session.isValid()) {
                        return reject();
                    }
                    const token = session.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
                    return resolve(token);
                });
            });
        }
```

#### 2. Use the token to query the API

I believe using a custom `httpClient` is indeed the best approach here. You almost had it working :).

Here is an example adapted from the [`ra-data-json-server` documentation](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-json-server#adding-custom-headers):

```
import { fetchUtils, Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import jsonServerProvider from 'ra-data-json-server';

const getJwtToken = async () => { /* ... */ };
const httpClient = async (url: string, options: any = {}) => {
    options.user = {
        authenticated: true,
        token: await getJwtToken(),
    };
    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
};
const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com', httpClient);

render(
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} title="Example Admin">
       ...
    </Admin>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This should be enough to include the Bearer Token to each API call.

Hope this helps! :)